# How can I track user geolocation information (latitude, longitude) with Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, google-bigquery, latitude-longitude, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Analytics standard events as well my own custom events in My App.

Assuming that my user already hast granted access to geolocation information I want to also include in the event GeoLocation Information (Latitude & Longitude) in the event payload. Ideally via geolocation_latitude & geolocation_longitude fields.

My goal is to consume this information in the Firebase Analytics (Dashboard) and run queries in the Google BigQuery. For example track region where users created more comments.

Firebase supports Latitude/Longitude metadata natively or I'll have to create my own schema?

Any ideias how to achieve this? Assuming that I'll like to run queries with this data what is the best way to encode the fields for maximum performance, usability when using BigQuery?

tks

Comment: I don't think Google will approve this. Of course, it is easy... just get user's lat/lng and send it as an event.

Comment: Did u achieve anything else using firebase?

Comment: @slanecek I'm curious why Google would veto queries using my own data?